# Is this a good (partial) autocorrelation or bad?

Tags: time-series, auto-correlation

I was playing with some data on deviation of close prices from its smoothed estimated and got these ACF and partial ACFs:
[image: ACF and partial ACF]

I still struggle to get proper intuition to the ACF plots. What do the plots tell me? That I need more than 100 steps in time for the AR model?

Comment: What you are seeing here is that the price level is highly autocorrelated, the price on day T+1 is not much different from the price on day T. To avoid this problem, most quants work with daily *changes* in price (or daily returns), which are approximately uncorrelated.